# How do I place the cursor and highlight a word programmatically? c#

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I place the cursor and highlight a word programmatically?

For example, in a WPF TextBox -> gTBxInfo.Text = "this is the fox and the cat".  I want to highlight the word "fox".

int iIdx = stInfo.IndexOf("fox") finds the location, and int iLength = 3 has the length.

In real life, I don't know what was entered in the TextBox.  When the customer enters a word (such as "fox") in another text box, the word "fox" needs to be highlighted in the gTBxInfo TextBox.

I've tried:

```
gTBxInfo.SelectionStart = iIdx; 
gTBxInfo.SelectionLength = iLength;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing one line of code:

```
gTBxInfo.SelectionStart = iIdx; 
gTBxInfo.SelectionLength = iLength;
gTBxInfo.Focus();
```

You need to set the focus on the `TextBox` before the highlight appears.